# How to remove label from multiple (closed) issues in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I wonder how to remove a label "e.g. `in Progress`" from multiple issues in GitLab.

I know the multiple-edit screen, but there isn't a way (as far as I can see) to "unlabel" a single (or all) labels. It's only to add new ones?!?

[image]

**BTW:**
Is there a way to remove a label if a merge is done, and the Merge-Comment `close` this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the removal of labels through calls to the GitLab API. See [GitLab API: Edit Issue](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#edit-issue), and the `remove_labels` and `state_event` attributes.

AFAIK, there isn't a way to remove a tag from multiple issues via the UI.